# Button disappears on Github Pages but not local file

Tags: javascript, html, github, github-pages

I have a project that I put onto Github and made a Github Page for it as well. There are multiple buttons all over the page, that have various functions attached to them. For some reason, this particular button doesn't want to show up on my Github Page. It shows up fine on my local copy, and when you inspect the area on Github Pages you can see the html, but it just doesn't show up! The button in question is the "Add to Top of Deck" button.

```
<div class="collapsible-body">
     <button id="add-discard" class="btn deep-purple lighten-2 m-10">Add to Discard</button>
     <button id="add-top" class="btn deep-purple lighten-2 m-10">Add to Top of Deck</button>
     <div id="hq-cards"></div>
</div>
```

A list of things I have tried:

- putting that button first
- putting that button second
- wrapping the buttons in a div
- wrapping just that button in a div

Also important to note: I'm literally only using HTML, CSS, Javascript, & JQuery for this build.

Also this might literally only apply in my current window of chrome. I just opened this in incognito mode and the button was there. This does nothing to lessen my confusion.

Comment: _"you can see the html, but it just doesn't show up"_  sounds like a CSS problem then. Check the element in your browser's _Elements_ console to see what styles are applied

Comment: _"I just opened this in incognito mode and the button was there"_  sounds like an Ad-Blocker problem

Answer (score 0):

The issue is consistent on my localhost. And, I found that paragraph element with id="add-top" will also disappear. Maybe you can work around it by renaming the id name of the button. I can't find why with the specific id name of "add-top", the element will disappear with ad-blocker enabled browser.

```html
    <div class="collapsible-body">
        <button id="add-discard" class="btn deep-purple lighten-2 m-10">Add to Discard</button>
        <button id="add-to-top" class="btn deep-purple lighten-2 m-10">Add to Top of Deck</button>
        <p id="add-top"> This is add top paragraph </p>
        <div id="hq-cards"></div>
    </div>
```